# Meteor error: Fiber is not defined

Tags: meteor, npm, fiber

I use fiber wrapper for async calls, for example when I need make record in database. But today I have an error: "Fiber is not defined.". I try reinstall fiber with npm but this is doesn't help me.

Comment: Did you update Meteor recently? In the current version you need to call `Fiber = Npm.require('fibers')`, have you done this?

Comment: Yes this helped me..!

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you install the Fiber in .meteor/local/build/server/ of your project folder.